# How to run cargo-expand against a build script?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get the macro-expanded source code of a program written in Rust. So far I've always used [cargo-expand](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-expand) for that. This time however, the macros are inside a [build script](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html), and I cannot seem to find a way to let `cargo expand` know, what I'm after.

Can I use cargo-expand to expand a build script? If so, what's the command line to use (assuming the build script is called *build.rs* and resides in the crate's root directory). If it isn't possible to use cargo-expand for this, what is the alternative?

Comment: I guess no: https://github.com/dtolnay/cargo-expand/issues/73

Comment: I guess `rustc -Zunstable-options --pretty=expanded build.rs` is a good start

Comment: @sta That won't work. It's failing due to cargo not setting up the environment required by the build script.